# Running JS on Flutter vs React Native

Tags: flutter, react-native

Me and my team are going to write an app for android and ios. It's a web3 thing and it requires the use of quite a complex library with API that's written in JavaScript.
We want to use Flutter, while our client says that RN seems like a better choice as it handles JS stuff by default. Are there any efficient solutions for using JS in Flutter that we could present that may be equally good or even better than the one in RN?

What I got from my research so far:

There's a package [flutter_js](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js) but it doesn't look very good. From what it seems, it stringifies everything and evaluates it in Dart. And since the JS API is complex, I'm afraid it may not work as intended.

I also found a post here with [this reply](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/rbconc/comment/hns9ypo/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) but from what I understand, this solution still requires stringifying everything, then hosting it on a webView, and then exchanging messages between it and our app, am I correct? Does this solution even work on mobile apps?

In RN, based on [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479180/what-does-react-native-use-to-allow-javascript-to-be-executed-on-ios-and-android/71239035#71239035) there's a JSI that completely eliminates the need to stringify everything and making React Native faster altogether as the stringification is the bottleneck currently.

So, is there anything in Flutter that could beat the JSI solution from RN? Can a fast and effective app be created using JS library with Flutter?